# Gain deficit and phase margin at crossover

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, control-system, bode-plot

I went through an exercise of the following specifications:

A voltage mode buck converter working in CCM mode works with:

\$V_{in}\$ min = 10V,
 \$V_{in}\$ max = 20V
\$R_{load}\$ min = 2.5 ohm
\$R_{load}\$ max = 50 ohm
L=75uH,
\$r_l\$ = 100 mohm (series resistance of the inductor)
C=220uF
ESR=70m ohm.

The PWM block using 2V peak to peak

The frequency of switching Fs= 100kHz

The question is, what is the phase shift and gain deficit at crossover frequency \$F_c = 5kHz\$?

I have simulated the model, and I have found the following approximative values, G=-8.75dB PS=-158°

In the other side, the other found G=-9.2dB and PS=-146°

Comment: Can you please post the circuit you have simulated? Also, it is important to make sure both approaches (you and the others) have agreed on the various ohmic losses in the converter (\$r_L\$ and \$r_C\$ for instance but the switch \$r_{DS(on)}\$ and the diode dynamic resistance \$r_d\$ also play a role). The control-to-output transfer function of the CCM-operated voltage-mode buck is that of a 2nd-order filter affected by a dc gain.

Comment: Vin max cannot be less than Vin min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control-to-output transfer function of the CCM buck converter operated in voltage-mode control is that of a 2nd-order system. The small-signal equivalent model is shown below:

[image]

If we determine the control-to-output transfer function using fast analytical circuits techniques or [FACTs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371) (how a stimulus on \$V_{err}\$ propagates and forms a response in \$V_{out}\$), we should find:

\$H(s)=H_0\frac{1+\frac{s}{\omega_z}}{1+\frac{s}{\omega_0Q}+(\frac{s}{\omega_0})^2}\$ with:

\$H_0=\frac{R}{r_L+R}\frac{V_{in}}{V_p}\$, \$\omega_z=\frac{1}{r_CC}\$, \$Q\approx\frac{1}{\frac{Z_0}{r_L+R}+\frac{r_C+r_L||R}{Z_0}}\$, \$Z_0=\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$ and \$\omega_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{LC\frac{R+r_C}{R+r_L}}}\$

If I now capture these data in a Mathcad sheet, the results you want at 5 kHz (assuming the minimum input voltage of 10 V and the maximum output current) are given below and are close to what others have found: 9.1 dB of attenuation and a 146° of phase shift:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected my model, the mistake was in Quality factor expression

Comment: Perfect, glad if this could help!